# Intel Xeon Phi turbostat For All Cores

Tags: linux, xeon

I am using a platform which as four `Intel Xeon Phi 7210`. To capture frequency and other parameters during runtime, I am using `turbostat`. However, `turbostat` won't show details of all the cores, but only one of the `Intel Xeon Phi 7210`.

**Questions**

- I am not able to understand why for cores `0-64` the data is being shown and now for rest of the cores `65-255`?
- Is it because of which package the `turbostat` is running on? For below case, may be it is running on package containing `0-64` core ids?
- Is it possible to know which `MSR` `turbostat` uses to capture these details? In `sysfs` I can't find interface on how to capture per core utilization and temperature. I know `turbostat` is using `MSR`, but not able to figure out how to get the exact `MSR` for these details.

Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks.

**System Details**

```
        -> hostnamectl
          Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
               CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
                    Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
              Architecture: x86-64
        -> lscpu
        Architecture:          x86_64
        CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
        Byte Order:            Little Endian
        CPU(s):                256
        On-line CPU(s) list:   0-255
        Thread(s) per core:    4
        Core(s) per socket:    64
        Socket(s):             1
        NUMA node(s):          2
        Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
        CPU family:            6
        Model:                 87
        Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon Phi(TM) CPU 7210 @ 1.30GHz
        Stepping:              1
        CPU MHz:               1194.273
        BogoMIPS:              2600.01
        Virtualization:        VT-x
        L1d cache:             32K
        L1i cache:             32K
        L2 cache:              1024K
        NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-255
        NUMA node1 CPU(s):
```

**Output of `turbostat`**

```
  CPU Avg_MHz   %Busy Bzy_MHz TSC_MHz     SMI  CPU%c1  CPU%c6 CoreTmp  PkgTmp Pkg%pc3 Pkg%pc6 PkgWatt RAMWatt   PKG_%   RAM_%
   -       4    0.27    1286    1324       0    0.24   99.49      24      31    0.39   77.82   49.36    2.47    0.00    0.00
   0      12    0.89    1289    1358       0    0.25   98.86      24      31    0.38   75.88   49.36    2.47    0.00    0.00
  64       2    0.15    1240    1358       0    0.99
 128       3    0.25    1273    1358       0    0.89
 192       3    0.26    1274    1359       0    0.89
   1       2    0.19    1210    1359       0    0.21   99.60      24
  65       2    0.15    1221    1358       0    0.24
 129       3    0.26    1254    1358       0    0.14
 193       4    0.27    1252    1358       0    0.12
   2       2    0.19    1239    1358       0    1.04   98.77      21
  66      13    0.94    1289    1358       0    0.29
 130       2    0.17    1252    1359       0    1.07
 194       5    0.34    1276    1359       0    0.90
   3       3    0.24    1220    1357       0    0.25   99.51      21
  67       2    0.17    1214    1357       0    0.32
 131       4    0.30    1253    1357       0    0.19
 195       4    0.29    1256    1357       0    0.19
   4       4    0.27    1246    1357       0    0.14   99.59      21
  68       2    0.15    1244    1357       0    0.26
 132       2    0.17    1261    1357       0    0.25
 196       3    0.24    1274    1357       0    0.17
   5       4    0.27    1254    1357       0    0.16   99.57      20
  69       2    0.16    1228    1357       0    0.27
 133       2    0.16    1239    1357       0    0.27
 197       4    0.27    1262    1357       0    0.17
   6       3    0.24    1259    1357       0    0.29   99.47      22
  70       2    0.16    1242    1357       0    0.37
 134       3    0.24    1269    1356       0    0.18
 198       3    0.25    1270    1356       0    0.17
   7       4    0.28    1251    1356       0    0.19   99.52      22
  71       2    0.18    1231    1356       0    0.30
 135       4    0.31    1267    1356       0    0.16
 199       4    0.33    1267    1356       0    0.14
   8       3    0.26    1268    1354       0    0.23   99.50      22
  72       3    0.26    1268    1354       0    0.24
 136       3    0.25    1276    1352       0    0.13
 200       3    0.25    1276    1352       0    0.14
   9       2    0.16    1223    1352       0    0.30   99.53      22
  73       3    0.22    1254    1352       0    0.24
 137       3    0.26    1264    1352       0    0.21
 201       3    0.23    1259    1351       0    0.13
  10       2    0.16    1245    1351       0    0.27   99.57      23
  74       2    0.14    1247    1351       0    0.29
 138       3    0.25    1276    1351       0    0.18
 202       2    0.16    1258    1351       0    0.27
  11       5    0.39    1267    1349       0    0.13   99.48      23
  75       4    0.28    1266    1349       0    0.24
 139       5    0.36    1272    1349       0    0.16
 203       2    0.15    1240    1349       0    0.37
  12       3    0.23    1262    1346       0    0.36   99.41      19
  76       3    0.25    1272    1345       0    0.26
 140       2    0.15    1258    1343       0    0.24
 204       3    0.21    1270    1343       0    0.18
  13       2    0.17    1220    1343       0    0.32   99.51      19
  77       4    0.28    1264    1343       0    0.21
 141       2    0.17    1247    1343       0    0.32
 205       3    0.24    1258    1342       0    0.13
  14       2    0.15    1243    1342       0    0.63   99.22      22
  78       2    0.14    1249    1340       0    0.55
 142       4    0.34    1281    1340       0    0.35
 206       3    0.25    1274    1339       0    0.36
  15       3    0.25    1250    1338       0    0.29   99.46      22
  79       4    0.28    1262    1337       0    0.20
 143       4    0.31    1266    1337       0    0.17
 207       4    0.31    1271    1337       0    0.17
  16       2    0.14    1241    1337       0    0.30   99.55      22
  80       3    0.24    1273    1337       0    0.21
 144       3    0.14    2417    1337       0    0.31
 208       3    0.22    1271    1336       0    0.11
  17       4    0.29    1258    1336       0    0.21   99.49      22
  81       3    0.21    1255    1336       0    0.30
 145       4    0.28    1271    1335       0    0.15
 209       4    0.28    1262    1335       0    0.15
  18       3    0.24    1264    1335       0    0.36   99.40      21
  82       3    0.26    1276    1334       0    0.26
 146       2    0.15    1259    1334       0    0.37
 210       3    0.23    1273    1332       0    0.17
  19       2    0.19    1234    1332       0    0.32   99.49      22
  83       3    0.24    1256    1332       0    0.27
 147       4    0.19    2005    1332       0    0.32
 211       3    0.24    1261    1331       0    0.16
  20       4    0.33    1264    1331       0    0.18   99.49      21
  84       5    0.36    1277    1331       0    0.14
 148       4    0.34    1274    1331       0    0.17
 212       5    0.17    2891    1331       0    0.34
  21       3    0.22    1216    1328       0    0.19   99.59      21
  85       3    0.26    1242    1328       0    0.15
 149       3    0.24    1241    1328       0    0.17
 213       3    0.21    1191    1328       0    0.20
  22       2    0.17    1247    1327       0    0.23   99.61      21
  86       3    0.26    1274    1327       0    0.13
 150       2    0.14    1249    1327       0    0.25
 214       3    0.26    1275    1327       0    0.14
  23       2    0.16    1224    1327       0    0.27   99.57      21
  87       3    0.27    1266    1327       0    0.16
 151       4    0.32    1269    1327       0    0.11
 215       4    0.31    1271    1327       0    0.12
  24       3    0.16    1992    1327       0    0.30   99.54      22
  88       2    0.14    1256    1326       0    0.23
 152       3    0.26    1275    1325       0    0.10
 216       3    0.25    1274    1326       0    0.11
  25       2    0.15    1215    1326       0    0.23   99.62      22
  89       2    0.14    1231    1326       0    0.24
 153       3    0.26    1262    1326       0    0.12
 217       3    0.26    1261    1326       0    0.12
  26       3    0.15    2002    1326       0    0.48   99.36      21
  90       2    0.14    1255    1324       0    0.41
 154       3    0.21    1269    1323       0    0.24
 218       3    0.20    1266    1322       0    0.17
  27       4    0.32    1260    1322       0    0.18   99.49      21
  91       2    0.14    1267    1322       0    0.36
 155       4    0.31    1269    1322       0    0.19
 219       4    0.32    1271    1322       0    0.18
  28       6    0.46    1255    1322       0    0.25   99.29      21
  92       5    0.37    1278    1322       0    0.34
 156       5    0.38    1280    1322       0    0.34
 220       5    0.37    1277    1322       0    0.35
  29       3    0.21    1226    1322       0    0.26   99.53      21
  93       2    0.17    1235    1322       0    0.30
 157       4    0.28    1260    1322       0    0.19
 221       3    0.27    1256    1322       0    0.20
  30       2    0.16    1247    1322       0    0.36   99.48      23
  94       5    0.35    1281    1322       0    0.17
 158       4    0.34    1282    1322       0    0.18
 222       5    0.15    3099    1322       0    0.38
  31       2    0.18    1231    1320       0    0.22   99.59      22
  95       2    0.17    1246    1319       0    0.24
 159       4    0.27    1265    1319       0    0.13
 223       4    0.28    1266    1319       0    0.13
  32       2    0.18    1249    1319       0    0.35   99.48      22
  96       4    0.34    1281    1319       0    0.18
 160       4    0.34    1282    1319       0    0.18
 224       5    0.35    1281    1319       0    0.17
  33       5    0.40    1269    1319       0    0.13   99.47      21
  97       5    0.39    1275    1319       0    0.14
 161       5    0.39    1275    1319       0    0.14
 225       5    0.39    1274    1319       0    0.14
  34       2    0.17    1249    1320       0    0.33   99.50      21
  98       5    0.36    1284    1320       0    0.14
 162       5    0.36    1281    1320       0    0.15
 226       5    0.36    1283    1320       0    0.15
  35       5    0.38    1268    1320       0    0.11   99.51      21
  99       2    0.17    1241    1320       0    0.32
 163       5    0.37    1275    1320       0    0.13
 227       5    0.37    1273    1320       0    0.13
  36       5    0.42    1280    1317       0    0.14   99.44      21
 100       5    0.39    1284    1317       0    0.17
 164       5    0.39    1285    1317       0    0.17
 228       5    0.38    1284    1317       0    0.18
  37       4    0.30    1256    1317       0    0.19   99.50      21
 101       2    0.16    1237    1316       0    0.25
 165       4    0.28    1265    1316       0    0.13
 229       4    0.28    1265    1316       0    0.13
  38       5    0.41    1279    1316       0    0.14   99.44      21
 102       5    0.39    1285    1316       0    0.16
 166       5    0.38    1284    1316       0    0.17
 230       5    0.40    1263    1316       0    0.16
  39       3    0.27    1254    1316       0    0.35   99.39      21
 103       2    0.16    1239    1315       0    0.37
 167       2    0.17    1246    1315       0    0.35
 231       4    0.29    1266    1313       0    0.15
  40       2    0.19    1253    1312       0    0.32   99.49      21
 104       5    0.35    1283    1312       0    0.15
 168       5    0.36    1282    1312       0    0.15
 232       5    0.35    1281    1312       0    0.16
  41       2    0.19    1237    1312       0    0.24   99.57      21
 105       2    0.17    1246    1312       0    0.26
 169       4    0.28    1262    1312       0    0.15
 233       3    0.27    1267    1312       0    0.16
  42       2    0.17    1244    1311       0    0.30   99.53      23
 106       2    0.14    1308    1311       0    0.33
 170       3    0.26    1273    1311       0    0.20
 234       3    0.27    1274    1311       0    0.19
  43       5    0.38    1269    1311       0    0.13   99.49      23
 107       2    0.15    1240    1311       0    0.35
 171       5    0.37    1275    1311       0    0.13
 235       5    0.37    1277    1311       0    0.14
  44       2    0.19    1255    1311       0    0.34   99.47      21
 108       5    0.35    1282    1311       0    0.15
 172       5    0.36    1281    1311       0    0.15
 236       5    0.35    1283    1311       0    0.16
  45       4    0.28    1257    1311       0    0.21   99.51      21
 109       2    0.17    1242    1310       0    0.23
 173       4    0.28    1268    1310       0    0.12
 237       4    0.29    1268    1310       0    0.11
  46       2    0.17    1244    1310       0    0.33   99.51      21
 110       5    0.35    1281    1310       0    0.14
 174       4    0.35    1280    1310       0    0.15
 238       4    0.34    1282    1310       0    0.15
  47       2    0.17    1227    1310       0    0.28   99.55      21
 111       2    0.16    1242    1310       0    0.28
 175       4    0.28    1267    1310       0    0.16
 239       3    0.26    1266    1310       0    0.18
  48       3    0.23    1262    1310       0    0.33   99.44      23
 112       4    0.34    1278    1310       0    0.22
 176       4    0.33    1281    1310       0    0.23
 240       4    0.34    1281    1310       0    0.22
  49       5    0.36    1263    1307       0    0.13   99.51      23
 113       2    0.16    1238    1307       0    0.33
 177       5    0.35    1272    1307       0    0.14
 241       4    0.35    1272    1307       0    0.14
  50       4    0.29    1259    1307       0    0.33   99.38      20
 114       5    0.36    1278    1307       0    0.25
 178       5    0.36    1278    1307       0    0.25
 242       5    0.36    1275    1307       0    0.25
  51       5    0.40    1254    1307       0    0.13   99.47      20
 115       2    0.19    1225    1307       0    0.34
 179       5    0.39    1264    1307       0    0.14
 243       5    0.38    1264    1307       0    0.14
  52       2    0.20    1240    1307       0    0.54   99.26      24
 116       7    0.58    1285    1307       0    0.16
 180       5    0.37    1277    1307       0    0.37
 244       5    0.37    1278    1307       0    0.37
  53       3    0.21    1221    1307       0    0.31   99.49      24
 117       5    0.39    1270    1307       0    0.13
 181       5    0.39    1271    1307       0    0.12
 245       5    0.19    2625    1307       0    0.32
  54       2    0.19    1246    1304       0    0.27   99.54      21
 118       4    0.33    1276    1305       0    0.14
 182       4    0.29    1277    1305       0    0.17
 246       4    0.33    1277    1305       0    0.14
  55       3    0.26    1248    1305       0    0.28   99.46      22
 119       3    0.27    1259    1304       0    0.20
 183       4    0.33    1269    1304       0    0.13
 247       4    0.32    1267    1304       0    0.14
  56       3    0.23    1252    1304       0    0.32   99.45      24
 120       4    0.29    1273    1304       0    0.26
 184       4    0.28    1271    1304       0    0.27
 248       2    0.20    1260    1304       0    0.35
  57       2    0.20    1217    1304       0    0.27   99.53      24
 121       2    0.20    1236    1303       0    0.27
 185       4    0.31    1256    1303       0    0.16
 249       2    0.18    1230    1302       0    0.16
  58       2    0.17    1237    1302       0    0.24   99.59      22
 122       2    0.15    1250    1302       0    0.26
 186       3    0.26    1273    1302       0    0.14
 250       3    0.25    1274    1302       0    0.15
  59       4    0.32    1255    1302       0    0.17   99.52      22
 123       2    0.17    1241    1302       0    0.32
 187       4    0.33    1268    1302       0    0.16
 251       4    0.34    1270    1302       0    0.15
  60       3    0.21    1260    1302       0    0.31   99.48      22
 124       4    0.32    1276    1302       0    0.19
 188       4    0.29    1272    1302       0    0.23
 252       4    0.32    1273    1302       0    0.20
  61       2    0.18    1211    1302       0    0.25   99.57      22
 125       2    0.17    1231    1302       0    0.26
 189       4    0.28    1259    1302       0    0.15
 253       4    0.28    1254    1302       0    0.15
  62       3    0.21    1240    1302       0    0.31   99.47      23
 126       4    0.35    1275    1302       0    0.18
 190       4    0.35    1275    1302       0    0.18
 254       4    0.35    1274    1302       0    0.17
  63       3    0.26    1223    1302       0    0.33   99.41      23
 127       2    0.17    1226    1302       0    0.41
 191       4    0.31    1257    1302       0    0.27
 255       6    0.33    1856    1302       0    0.26
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xeon Phi processor you're using does not have 256 cores. It has 64 cores, each of which has 4 threads (for a total of 256 threads). Only the cores have frequencies and temperatures -- threads don't have separate values for those attributes. (They're effectively shared across all threads on a core.)

The CPUs numbered 0-63 in the output of `turbostat` represent the 64 cores, and the first thread on each of those cores. The ones numbered 64-255 represent the additional three threads on each core.

Comment: .@duskwuff - Then why `lscpu` log in the question shows `CPU(s):                256` and `On-line CPU(s) list:   0-255` ? Also, there is a different `sysfs` (`cpufreq`) for each of the 256 cores.

Comment: Because that tool is counting logical cores as "CPU(s)".